# jQuery: Toggle rotate div on click function

Tags: html, rotation, jquery

I'm trying to work out if it's possible to toggle the rotation of a div on a click function, e.g. Clicking on a menu button rotates the arrow from pointing downwards to upwards and clicking again will reverse this (upwards to downwards).
I have a jsfiddle demo setup which will make more sense of it: http://jsfiddle.net/bf7Ke/1/

jQuery —

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.menu-category-title').click(function(){
              $('#menu-'+$(this).attr('hook')).fadeToggle('slow');
              $(this).children('.menu-title-arrow').rotate({animateTo:180});

        return false;
    });
});
```

Thus far clicking on `.menu-category-title` fades in the relevant content below and rotates the corresponding arrow by 180 degrees. Clicking `.menu-category-title` again fades out the relevant content but the arrow stays at 180 degrees. Is there anyway to toggle this function also?
I can't figure it out, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: this one also worked for you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37452477/rotate-div-text-after-clicking-on-button-using-jquery-and-css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think you should check if element is visible or not before arrow rotation

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.menu-category-title').click(function(){
        var elem = $('#menu-'+$(this).attr('hook')),
            arrow = $(this).children('.menu-title-arrow')

        if (!elem.is(':visible'))  {
            arrow.rotate({animateTo:180});
        } else {
            arrow.rotate({animateTo:360});
        }
        elem.fadeToggle('slow', function() {
        });

    return false;
   });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bf7Ke/2/

Comment: this one worked out as the best solution, cheers for your help, exactly what I was after :)

Comment: What's the `return false` for? and why not to invert the logic by simply `if (elem.is(':visible'))  {` <-- swap logic inside? Since when attr `hook` is a valid HTML attribute?

Comment: What's the return false for? - was in original code, not needed at all as I see
why not to invert the logic by simply if (elem.is(':visible')) { just because I was in hurry =)

Answer (score 2):

How about this to fit your need: http://jsfiddle.net/HMKXq/

OR bit of the animated demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/HMKXq/2/

Good source: [Rotate image on toggle with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999321/rotate-image-on-toggle-with-jquery)

Hope it helps `:)`

**code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.menu-category-title').click(function () {
        $('#menu-' + $(this).attr('hook')).fadeToggle('slow');
        $(this).children('.menu-title-arrow').toggleClass("rotate1 rotate2");

    });
});
```

**css**

```
.menu-category-title {
    position: relative;
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.menu-food-wrap {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 45px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 15px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    display: none;
}
.rotate1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transition:.5s;
    -ms-transition:.5s;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
    transition:.5s;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0);
}
.rotate2 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
    -o-transition:.5s;
    -ms-transition:.5s;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
    transition:.5s;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=2);
}
```

Comment: nice example, (I just hate those -browser-specifics) but hopefully your version is less code that using an additional plugin, just I'm concerned about older browsers that might be covered by the plugin.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Agreed, +1 Bruvo. OP please do check browser. Hope you are well Roko `B-)`. Although I would recommend to OP to upgrade browser as the JQ version OP is using is 1.8.3 which is quick latest. `:))` Why to use ferrari to moe the lawn :)

Comment: `°D°` +1 Good explanation. and another +1 for asking me if my coffee is hot enough ;) nice to see you around.

Answer (score 1):

`return false` is not needed in your case, additionally `hook` attribute is not a HTML attribute, therefore it's invalid.
**Use `data-hook` attribute instead.**

<kbd>**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bf7Ke/3/)**</kbd>

```
<div class="menu-category-title" data-hook="01">
```

Than do like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.menu-category-title').click(function () {
        var dat = $(this).data('rotate');
        $(this).data('rotate', !dat? 0 : 180);
        $('#menu-' + $(this).data('hook')).fadeToggle('slow');
        $(this).children('.menu-title-arrow').rotate({animateTo: dat});
    });
});
```

what this does is setting an additional `data` (`rotate`) on click, than using a `ternary operator ( ? : )` set respectively to `0 : 180` depending on the boolean/value returned by var `dat`.

Comment: oh +1 hope your coffee is hot enough `:P`

Answer (score 0):

You need to restore the div's angle to 0 when closing the div. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.menu-category-title').click(function(){
              var targetAngle = $('#menu-'+$(this).attr('hook')).is(":visible") ? 0 : 180;
              $('#menu-'+$(this).attr('hook')).fadeToggle('slow');
              $(this).children('.menu-title-arrow').rotate({animateTo:targetAngle});

        return false;
    });
});
```

Here's an updated jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/rFxJM/