# Rotate text link on click

Tags: jquery, html, rotation, jquery-animate

I'm a beginner at javascripting. I would like to know how to code a div that moves up and down within a container when clicked on a text link.

it's the text rotation part where I don't understand. I think I can use jquery animate css top adjustment to trigger the moving of the div up and down.

but i don't know how to script .click function > trigger div down, arrow text rotates up ^, else trigger div up, arrow text rotates down v(or returns to original state which is down arrow v).

i found a similar answer that I would like to achieve [jQuery: Toggle rotate div on click function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16825078/jquery-toggle-rotate-div-on-click-function) it would be great if i did know how to use if() statements. I can't figure out what to put inside! T_T

an example would be the top black panel of [this website](http://pixelkit.com/previews/flat-icon-set), where there's a small arrow tab on the right side of the page that triggers the top panel to hide/show or move up/down.

Comment: If you could post the code you're currently need help with it would make it easier to know where you are stuck and how people can help.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

Working example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/GaJBy/1/

Please mind that it is using 3rd party jQueryRotate plugin (http://www.nealfletcher.co.uk/js/jQueryRotate.js).

CSS:

```
#outerDiv {
    position: relative; 
    height: 300px; 
    width: 300px; 
    background: #FFF; 
    border: 1px solid #A0A0A0
}

#innerDiv {
    position: absolute; 
    border: 1px solid #CCC; 
    width: 50px; 
    height: 50px; 
    vertical-align: middle; 
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 36px
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="outerDiv">
    <div id="innerDiv">↓</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#innerDiv").click(function () { // Attach click listener
    var duration = 500;
    // If the square is not at the top, go down otherwise go back up       
    if (parseInt($(this).css("top")) > 0) {
        finalPosition = 0;
        startingAngle = 180;
        endingAngle = 0;
    } else {
        finalPosition = $("#outerDiv").height() - $(this).height();
        startingAngle = 0;
        endingAngle = 180;
    }

    $(this).rotate({
        angle: startingAngle,
        animateTo: endingAngle,
        duration: duration
    });

    $(this).animate({
        top: finalPosition
    }, duration);
});
```

Comment: Nice - but for those of us who have to support IE8, it's worth mentioning this only works in IE9+