# Selecting multiple li classes in a menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a portfolio site, and I'm struggling to select the proper elements with JQuery. My goal is to show/hide the `.inner` (Task) items when clicking the `.outer` (Category) items. I have `.arrow`s that rotate when the menu is expanded.

This is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16825078/jquery-toggle-rotate-div-on-click-function), and the accompanying [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bf7Ke/49/).

Thanks to [Tats_innit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1210059/tats-innit) for the original answer.

I have this HTML:

```
<li class="outer" hook="01">
    <div class="arrow"></div>
    Category 1
</li>
<li class="inner" id="menu-01">
    Task 1
</li>
<li class="inner" id="menu-01">
    Task 2
</li>
<li class="inner" id="menu-01">
    Task 3
</li>

<li class="outer" hook="02">
    <div class="arrow"></div>
    Category 2
</li>
<li class="inner" id="menu-02">
    Task 1
</li>
    <li class="inner" id="menu-02">
    Task 2
</li>
    <li class="inner" id="menu-02">
    Task 3
</li>
```

And this jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.outer').click(function(){
            var elem = $('#menu-'+$(this).attr('hook')),
                arrow = $(this).children('.arrow')

            if (!elem.is(':visible'))  {
                arrow.rotate({animateTo:90, duration:128});
            } else {
                arrow.rotate({animateTo:0, duration:128});
            }
            elem.slideToggle('128ms', function() {
            });

        return false;
    });
});
```

I understand that I need to change `var elem = $('#menu-'+$(this).attr('hook'))` but I'm not sure how to display *all* instances of `.inner`.
I didn't nest the `.inner` elements because I have a hover state `background-color: #f1f1f1;` for the `.outer` class.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? What is the desired output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem can be solved, but there are many things wrong with your approach in the first place, so I would like to aim to change those, instead. And then solve the problem.

1. [**The `id` attribute is unique**](http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/WCAG20/tests/test185.html). You cannot have multiple elements with the same `id` in the same page; for that reason, use `class`.
2. `hook` is **not a valid HTML attribute**; while it is true that this won't hurt you and browsers will most likely ignore it, I would rather see it [standardized as `data-hook` if you so wish](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/customattributes.shtml). This will allow you also to use the standard APIs.
3. You should nest the `.inner` inside the `.outer` because **it makes sense semantically and it will degrade gracefully** and be understandable to screen readers as well. The problem you mention about the background on hover, I think could be easily solved with some good CSS: though I didn't understand the specific issue, so I cannot say.

But fact is, that using nesting you probably don't need most of those ids, classes and random data attributes (unless obviously you need them for something else than just opening up a list).

After that you **HTML** will look like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="outer">
         <div class="arrow"></div>
         Category 1
         <ul>
             <li>
                 Task 1
             </li>
             <li>
                 Task 2
             </li>
             <li>
                 Task 3
             </li>
         </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="outer">
         <div class="arrow"></div>
         Category 1
         <ul>
             <li>
                 Task 1
             </li>
             <li>
                 Task 2
             </li>
             <li>
                 Task 3
             </li>
         </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And you **jQuery** like so:

```
$('.outer').click(function(){
    var elem  = $(this).children('ul'),
        arrow = $(this).children('.arrow')

    if (!elem.is(':visible'))  {
        arrow.rotate({animateTo:90, duration:128});
    } else {
        arrow.rotate({animateTo:0, duration:128});
    }
    elem.slideToggle('128ms', function() {
    });

    return false;
});
```

As a final note, `.arrow` is not a very semantic element, since it's not even used to activate the animation (the click is bound the the `li.outer`) I would remove it altogether and instead achieve the same effect using a [`pseudo-element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) on the said `li`, and perhaps rotate it with CSS3.

### Edit

I am not sure why you were not able to make it function properly; though you tell me that you appreciated the comment regarding the nesting, your *fiddle* didn't use the correct nesting.

In any case, I put up an example for you with the advice I gave you here, and basically I just copied the code *verbatim* as I wrote it here. I made a few adjustments, though: such as implementing the CSS pseudoelement and getting rid of that `div.arrow` element, which honestly looked bad.

Obviously is just an example, but it shows how think this problem should be approached. Hopefully it will solve your doubts:

[<kbd>**Working example**</kbd>](http://jsbin.com/EvidaKa/1)

Comment: I should have noted the appearance. Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SwankyLegg/D4vuB/5/) that indicates what I'm trying to achieve. I just need the menu items to appear. I appreciate the suggestion RE: nesting the list (and I understand the id/class distinction), but I still can't get this to function appropriately.

Comment: Edited my answer with a working example, see if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is my first foray into JQuery, so I was just working with an example (that I _didn't_ make myself) that did an approximation of what I was looking for.

Comment: Accepted. In case you're interested in what you helped create, here's the ["final" version](http://jsfiddle.net/SwankyLegg/ahA7N/3/).

Comment: Perfect! Very well done, kudos for using the `.svg`. Remember that IE8 doesn't support SVG, so you might want to have a fallback in case you are planning to support that 100%.

Answer (score 1):

You can nest a set of `outer` and `inner` into a `div`

```
<div>
    <li class="outer">
        <div class="arrow"></div>
        Category 1
    </li>
    <li class="inner">
        Task 1
    </li>
    <li class="inner">
        Task 2
    </li>
    <li class="inner">
        Task 3
    </li>
</div>
```

then your js code goes like

```
$('.outer').click(function(){
    var elem = $(this).siblings('.inner'),
        arrow = $(this).children('.arrow')

    if (!elem.is(':visible'))  {
        arrow.rotate({animateTo:90, duration:128});
    } else {
        arrow.rotate({animateTo:0, duration:128});
    }
    elem.slideToggle('128ms', function() {
    });

    return false;
});
```

won't affect your `background-color` for `outer` class in the meantime

Comment: This is _incredibly_ helpful. Works like a charm! This is my first foray in js/jquery, and it's been a struggle. Now if I can only create an expand/collapse all...

Comment: bind an event to your expand/collapse all button with following event handler code `$('.inner:visible').slideToggle('128ms', function(){ /**/ });` will do the trick

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li.inner').hide();
    $('.outer').click(function()
    {
        var elem = $(this).attr('hook');
        $('li.inner').hide();
        $(".menu-"+elem).toggle();
    });
});
</script>
<ul>
<li class="outer" hook="01">
<div class="arrow"></div>
Category 1
</li>
<li class="inner menu-01">
Task 1
</li>
<li class="inner menu-01">
Task 2
</li>
<li class="inner menu-01">
Task 3
</li>

<li class="outer" hook="02">
<div class="arrow"></div>
Category 2
</li>
<li class="inner menu-02">
Task 1
</li>
<li class="inner menu-02">
Task 2
</li>
<li class="inner menu-02">
Task 3
</li>
</ul>
```

first of all change li id to class because 2 li don't have same id

Comment: I appreciate the input, but I want this to animate beautifully. "Hide" and "Show" are very jarring. Functionality should come first, I suppose, but aesthetic determines appropriate jquery functions.

Comment: use this script
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('li.inner').hide();
 $('.outer').click(function()
 {
  var elem = $(this).attr('hook');
  $('li.inner').slideUp('slow');
  $(".menu-"+elem).slideDown('slow');
 });
});
</script>

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for [`nextUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/)

```
$(this).nextUntil('.outer').slideToggle('218ms');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bf7Ke/53/